# Convert inline assembly code to C++

Tags: c++, inline-assembly

I am working on a cpp project. The project need to be migrated to 64 bit. It contains some Inline assembly code which cannot compile on x64. 
This is the Function which contain the assembly code:

```
void ExternalFunctionCall::callFunction(ArgType resultType, void* resultBuffer)
{
#if defined(_NT_) || defined(__OS2__)

    // I386

    // just copy the args buffer to the stack (it's already layed out correctly)
    int* begin = m_argsBegin;
    int* ptr = m_argsEnd;
    int arr[1000], i=0;
    while (ptr > begin) {
        int val = *(--ptr);

        __asm push val
    }

    void* functionAddress = m_functionAddress;

    // call the function & handle the return value.  use __stdcall calling convention
    switch (resultType) {
    case voidType:
        __asm {
            call functionAddress
        }
        break;
    case pointerType:
    case int32Type:
        __asm {
            call functionAddress
            mov ebx, resultBuffer
            mov dword ptr [ebx],eax
        }
        break;
    case floatType:
        __asm {
            call functionAddress
            mov ebx, resultBuffer
            fstp dword ptr [ebx]
        }
        break;
    case doubleType:
        __asm {
            call functionAddress
            mov ebx, resultBuffer
            fstp qword ptr [ebx]
        }
        break;
    }
```

I used stack, array to migrate this "asm push val" but didn't work. Although, It don't throw any compilation error but logic didn't worked.

So, I want to ask, What can I use in C++ instead of "__asm push val". Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Surely this isn’t the only assembly instruction in the program? How do you use the pushed value? For the moment there isn’t enough information to help you.

Comment: You'll need to show more code so we can know what's being done with the value pushed onto the stack.

Comment: Standard C++ does not include inline assembly language or any operations for directly modifying the CPU's stack....  You've more  chance of useful advice if you explain what your function's doing with the stack afterwards?  If it's preparing values for a function call or something, there may be some other way to supply the arguments.  It's likely highly specific to your OS and/or compiler, which you haven't stated.

Comment: Is this some kind of "variable arguments" function call? If so, how wide is the range of arguments?

Comment: Hi Konrad/Michael/Tony/Mats, 

Now you can see the complete code of function, which contains the asm code.

Comment: Do you have any control about the function you call through `m_functionAddress`?

Answer (score 13):

The problem isn't solvable in general; that's because the comment,

```
// call the function & handle the return value.  use __stdcall calling convention
```

indicates reliance on *32bit calling conventions*.

In 32bit x86, `stdcall` means that *all* arguments are passed on the stack, in reverse order (i.e. the last arg is pushed first. That is, if `arg[0]` is at `addr` then `arg[1]`, no matter it's type, is at `addr + sizeof(arg[0])`). That's the reason why the following code in your sample:

```
// just copy the args buffer to the stack (it's already layed out correctly)
int* begin = m_argsBegin;
int* ptr = m_argsEnd;
int arr[1000], i=0;
while (ptr > begin) {
    int val = *(--ptr);

    __asm push val
}
```

actually can work - because it simply doesn't matter what exactly is there, what type the arguments are; all that's relevant is that each and every one of them is in a known memory location, and known-to-be-consecutive-in-memory. If you know that argument `N` is at `addr`, then you can know argument `N+1` is at `addr + sizeof(arg[N])`.

That's what the comment says, "*it's already layed out correctly*" - unfortunately, this is *not* true in 64bit mode. The code therefore cannot be "ported"; there is no equivalent to port to.

Calling conventions that are at least partially register based - as is Win64 on x64 (64bit x86) behave differently. For those, it depends on what types of arguments the called functions take (you can, in Windows, pass four integer-type args in general-purpose registers plus some float-type args in `XMM` registers). You therefore need to know *more* about the signature (prototype) of the function you call than simply "it takes `N` arguments" in order to be able to correctly marshal args from an "anycall" type wrapper like the above. In 64bit mode, for every function you'd wish to call through your wrapper, you need to know not just how many args there are in total, but also how many are in general-purpose regs, how many in `XMM` regs, and how many on the stack.

The "call a func through a pointer and copy the return value to a known location" part is portable and can be expressed in plain C/C++. But the part that gets the *arguments* for this, as per above, does *not port* in any straightforward way between 32bit `stdcall` and any 64bit x86 calling convention I know of (neither Win64/x64 nor the UN*X `x86_64` conventions allow to predict both the locations and total stack memory usage of all arguments for a function given just the number and types of the args but not their ordering).

What exactly you need to do depends *much more* on the callers/users of the above `class ExternalFunctionCall` than on the small little sample of inline assembly you've shown. It's particularly necessary to know how the members `m_argsBegin` and `m_argsEnd` are initialized and where. Can you provide a few more details on how the class looks like (all member variables/functions), as well as examples on its actual use ?

Comment: Thanks Frank, I would like to ask one more thing. Can't we separate this asm code in asm/s file? A separate asm file can compile on x64 through MASM64.exe. If possible, please tell me how can we do this?
We have migrated all other asm code to cpp, only "__asm push val" is remaining. You can see the code of complete function above.

Comment: @user2118116: as already stated, there's _more_ to do than simply "replace the `__asm push val` with some 64-bittishness". This "more" is _outside the function_ - it's _both_ in the entire class as well as, and that's where your biggest piece of work is, _at the actual places where instances of this class are created/used_. No easy way out here, sorry. Your question about porting this to 64bit is a bit like saying "my x86 code uses `lcall` in inline assembly and I need to port it to ARM, so I want to know the ARM instruction that does `lcall`".

Comment: @FrankH. Full ACK on this. I suggested the OP in a duplicate of this: 「The best thing you can do is to rewrite the entire function using [libffi](http://sourceware.org/libffi/) or [dyncall](http://dyncall.org/) instead.」

Answer (score 0):

There are several things which you need to solve. (I looked up your code on another question). As I understood this code is a wrapper to call pretty abstract function located at specified address which expects certain amount of data in stack and can return different things based in ArgType.

If you want to wrap it through plain C you have to define several functions prototypes (based on return value) to use then on your switch, but then you have to solve another problem, which is more tricky.

Problem with porting such things in C is that you don't know upfront an amount of arguments (data size) you have to push in stack, so you will have troubles defining prototype.

Let's say func(char c) will definitely push in stack 1 byte (but also not always right because of data alignments).. in your case you have to think about solution which will have set of parameters with an equal size to size of data you need to be on the stack. Which at first glance not something you can do straight away.

UPD. you can do it with func( char [] param ); but it also has issues which were explained in answer above.

Comment: You know, it's not that bad an answer, but the last paragraph, particularly "you have to think about solution", kind of ruins it for me. The OP wouldn't be asking for help if they could think of something. They obviously tried very hard to solve it on their own.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you.. May be 'you have to think' indeed was a bit hard, but I have excuse that I am not native English speaker.. I mean that I really don't know the exact solution for last step, and what I wrote was more kind of out laud thinking rather then ready made answer. And another thing is that from what I read in OP question (actually both of them), I would consider to be 'obviously tried very hard to solve' is applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a somewhat old question, but I just stumbled upon: [xbyak](https://github.com/herumi/xbyak).

Perhaps what you're looking for?

Comment: Hi Nix, 
I want to replace the asm code from this context:

    int* begin = m_argsBegin;
    int* ptr = m_argsEnd;
    int arr[1000], i=0;
    while (ptr > begin) {
    int val = *(--ptr);

    __asm push val
    }
Basically I want to replace the statement "__asm push val" with Cpp code. 
Thanks

Comment: What are m_argsBegin and m_argsEnd?

Comment: @Nix- Both of these are int*

Thanks