# Inline assembly language

Tags: c++, memory-management, assembly

I am doing 64 bit migration and i need to port inline assembly code to cpp Here is he code

```
void ExternalFunctionCall::callFunction(ArgType resultType, void* resultBuffer)
{
    // I386

    // just copy the args buffer to the stack (it's already layed out correctly)
    int* begin = m_argsBegin;
    int* ptr = m_argsEnd;
        while (ptr > begin) {
            int val = *(--ptr);
            __asm push val
        }
    }
```

I want to migrate this __asm push val to cpp. This function is called four times and for every call we get different values of m_argsBegin and m_argsEnd(both m_argsBegin and m_argsEnd are dynamic arrays).
This while loop executes 4 times for every call of this "callFunction" function. So, in total 4x4 = 16 values are to be stored in a "CONTINUOUS memory location"  this is what "__asm push val" does i guess. I need to implement this in c++ . I tried every possible way (stack, array, Lnked list, Queue even separated this into a separate asm file but none are working)
Can anyone help?

I separated this inline assembly function into a separate assembly file . Here is the code:

```
.386
 .model c,flat
  public callFunction_asm

CSEG segment public 'CODE'

 callFunction_asm PROC
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp 
    mov ecx, [ebp+8] ;val
    push dword ptr [ecx]
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
 RETN
 callFunction_asm ENDP
CSEG ends
END
```

where callFunction_asm is an extern function , I declared it as:

extern "C"
void callFunction_asm(int val);

and I am calling this function as:

```
while (ptr > begin) {
        int val = *(--ptr);
        callFunction_asm(val); //possible replacement
    }
```

but even this is not working, can anyone tell where am I going wrong. I am new to assembly coding.

Comment: [On the stack](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/The_Stack).

Comment: I know it will store it on stack i want to access the address of the stack. Cannot do using stack pointer as there is no stack declared in my project just this __asm push val is used

Comment: I don't see why that would matter. The `push` instruction will still use the stack pointer regardless of whether it has been set up properly when your program runs or not. You haven't specified which CPU architecture this is for, but many CPUs allow you to read the value of the stack pointer.

Comment: Do you really need the push? If you are porting the code to C++, why not store the value of 'val' in a previously defined array or vector? (like std::vector<int> v; while(...) { int val = ...; v.push_back(val); }

Comment: I tried using array and vector but my logic isn't working and yes i have to migrate this asm code to cpp.

Comment: One problem here is that it strongly depends on the code that *uses* the values that you placed on the stack as well. Could you show that code? Does it contain `__asm pop something`?

Comment: no it do not contain a pop statement plus since val is declared inside while loop so it cannot be available outside the while loop

Comment: Well it can, that loop is pushing to the stack .. an other loop after it could be popping the stuff back off again. There are other ways for the rest of the code to access that data though, like through a pointer. Anyway, regardless of how the other code is accessing those values on the stack, we'd have to see it first in order to come up with an idea of how to replace it.

Comment: The compiler reserves memory for local variables on the stack. You should post the full code, otherwise it is hard to say what the function is really doing, so it would be helpfull if you posted the whole function (and maybe also the caller).

Comment: Now you may see more code

Comment: Ok, that doesn't make any sense whatsoever. It pretends to set up the arguments for a call, but then it doesn't even make that call. Arguments disappear and nothing happens.

Comment: For more context and older answers, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142284/convert-inline-assembly-code-to-c

Comment: why did you remove the more extensive code samples from http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16294841/6 ?

Comment: Furthermore, depending on CPU, pushing a lot of stuff onto the stack, without popping before the function ends, will likely result in the function return address being replaced by garbage, causing the program to crash & burn. And also, it creates a memory leak on the stack.

Comment: @ mr_georg: Tried using array/vector/queue/list to sore the value nothing is working.

Answer (score 2):

`push` puts its operand on the stack, as well as decrementing the stack pointer.

If you looked at the stack pointer plus 1 (`1($sp)`), you should see the value (but if you wanted it back, you'd typically use `pop`).

Comment: I know it is pushing the value onto a stack but I want to know the location of that stack on the memory

Comment: @user2165634 See the second paragraph, where I explain it.

Comment: I cannot use __asm pop val to access the value as you see val is declared inside while loop and i want to access it's value outside the loop moreover i cannot define it outside the loop cause logic of my code doesn't work that way

Comment: @user2165634 Do some research on what the stack pointer is and what addressing modes are.

Comment: I did but 
There is no stack declared in my code only this single statement is there __asm push val
I cannot use stack pointer to access the address of stack

Comment: You can use `__asm pop eax` then `__asm mov val, eax` where `val` is the identifier for any variable still in scope (you can create another `val` outside the pushing loop, move the original `val` to be declared before that loop, or change `val` to some other variable.

Comment: @Skizz: oh cool - thanks for the correction - my asm's rusty!

Comment: I cannot use inline assembly code as i am migrating this project to 64 bit and inline assembly is not supported on 64 bit platform