# no such instruction .. gcc x86_64

Tags: gcc, assembly, instructions

I have this code block:

```
void CallAnyFunc(void *pfn, const std::vector<char> &arguments, CLR_DataType returnType, AnyFuncReturn &returnValue)
{
    int i4;
    float r4;
    double r8;
    long int i8;

    char* pStack;
    const char* i = arguments.empty() ? NULL : &*arguments.begin();
    const char* end = i + arguments.size();

    // Reserve the space on the stack
    // This is equivalent (in some sense) to 'push' all the parameters into the stack.
    // NOTE: Don't just subtract the stack pointer, better to call _alloca, because it also takes
    // care of ensuring all the consumed memory pages are accessible
#ifdef PLATFORM_WINDOWS
    _alloca(arguments.size());
#else
    alloca(arguments.size());
#endif

    _asm {
        mov pStack, esp
    };

    // Copy all the parameters into the stack
    // NOTE: Don't use the memcpy function. Because the call to it
    // will overwrite the stack (which we're currently building)
    while (i != end)
        *pStack++ = *i++;

    switch (returnType)
    {
        case DATATYPE_R4:
        {
            // Call your function
            _asm {
                call pfn
                fstp r4
            }

            returnValue.r4 = r4;
        } break;

        case DATATYPE_R8:
        {
            // Call your function
            _asm {
                call pfn
                fstp r8
            }

            returnValue.r8 = r8;
        } break;

        case DATATYPE_U8:
        case DATATYPE_I8:
        {
            // Call your function
            _asm {
                call pfn
                mov i8, eax
            }

            returnValue.i8 = i8;
        } break;

        default:
        {
            _asm {
                call pfn
                mov i4, eax
            };

            returnValue.i4 = i4;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically it is a bridge into calling CLR micro dot net.

When I compile with gcc provided with xcode I get:

```
nmfi/nmf_call.cpp:153:no such instruction: `movlq %esp, -96(%rbp)'
nmfi/nmf_call.cpp:164:indirect call without `*'
nmfi/nmf_call.cpp:175:indirect call without `*'
nmfi/nmf_call.cpp:187:indirect call without `*'
nmfi/nmf_call.cpp:190:no such instruction: `movlq %eax, -88(%rbp)'
nmfi/nmf_call.cpp:197:indirect call without `*'
```

where line 153 = line after mov pStack, esp
and line 190 = line after returnValue.i8 = i8 which is prob actually mov i8, eax

...

this code use to work just fine.  I'm figuring the change is because of x86_64 but am having problems figuring out how to write the "mov" properly so that it can be assembled.

...

related compiler flags:

```
CC := g++
CFLAGS := -c -DLITTLE_ENDIAN=1 -DGCC_V4_2 -fasm-blocks  \
        -DVERSION_MAJOR="4" -DVERSION_MINOR="2" -DVERSION_BUILD="1" -DVERSION_REVISION="0" \
        -DOEMSYSTEMINFOSTRING='"OSXBOI"'

# -DMAC -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden
AR := ar
ARFLAGS := rs

ifeq (,$(findstring Debug,$(CONFIG)))
    CFLAGS += -O3 -DNDEBUG
else
    CFLAGS += -g -D_DEBUG
endif
```

any hints?

Here is the revised code, this is untested, but it compiles.

```
void CallAnyFunc(void *_pfn, const std::vector<char> &arguments, CLR_DataType returnType, AnyFuncReturn &returnValue)
{
    int i4;
    float r4;
    double r8;
    long int i8;
    typedef void (*PFN)();
    PFN pfn = (PFN)_pfn;

    char* pStack;
    const char* i = arguments.empty() ? NULL : &*arguments.begin();
    const char* end = i + arguments.size();

    // Reserve the space on the stack
    // This is equivalent (in some sense) to 'push' all the parameters into the stack.
    // NOTE: Don't just subtract the stack pointer, better to call _alloca, because it also takes
    // care of ensuring all the consumed memory pages are accessible
#ifdef PLATFORM_WINDOWS
    _alloca(arguments.size());
#else
    alloca(arguments.size());
#endif

#ifdef X86_64
    _asm {
        mov pStack, rsp
    };
#else
    _asm {
        mov pStack, esp
    };
#endif

    // Copy all the parameters into the stack
    // NOTE: Don't use the memcpy function. Because the call to it
    // will overwrite the stack (which we're currently building)
    while (i != end)
        *pStack++ = *i++;

    switch (returnType)
    {
        case DATATYPE_R4:
        {
            // Call your function
            _asm {
                call *pfn
                fstp r4
            }

            returnValue.r4 = r4;
        } break;

        case DATATYPE_R8:
        {
            // Call your function
            _asm {
                call *pfn
                fstp r8
            }

            returnValue.r8 = r8;
        } break;

        case DATATYPE_U8:
        case DATATYPE_I8:
        {
#ifdef X86_64
            // Call your function
            _asm {
                call *pfn
                mov i8, rax
            }
#else
            _asm {
                call *pfn
                mov i8, eax
            }
#endif
            returnValue.i8 = i8;
        } break;

        default:
        {
#ifdef X86_64
            // Call your function
            _asm {
                call *pfn
                mov i4, eax
            }
#else
            _asm {
                call *pfn
                mov i4, eax
            }
#endif

            returnValue.i4 = i4;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're building 64-bit code the size of a pointer and long int will both be 64 bits. So you probably want to use `rsp` and `rax` rather than `esp` and `eax`.

Comment: you were right.  do you have any hints on the

"nmfi/nmf_call.cpp:170:indirect call without `*'"

which corresponds to the call pfn i believe.

perhaps I need to type it as a function pointer?

Comment: Michael, add your comment as an answer and I'll give you the points.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294841/inline-assembly-language and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142284/convert-inline-assembly-code-to-c - you can make this compile but it's not particularly "easy" to make this work in all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're building 64-bit code the size of a pointer and long int will both be 64 bits. You'll probably want to use `rsp` rather than `esp` for the pointer, in order to get all bits of the address.

For the `i8` variable you have some options: keep it as an `long int` (or better yet, `int64_t`) and use `rax` instead of `eax`. Or make it an `int32_t` and keep using `eax`.