# Call function at address with previously passed arguments

Tags: c, inline-assembly, calling-convention

I am trying to make a function to call other function which is located at some address.
The function that calls another functions only receives types of args passed in (as char*), return type and arguments itself.
But it suddenly crashes every time at calling function itself or after calling it.
Basically, what I am trying to reach, is write function like this in C++:

```
function callfunc(name,...) --Lua
 local func=_G[name];
 func(...)
end
```

So here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
void testfunc(char *c){
    printf("Text: %s\n",c);
}
void callfunc(void *ptr,char ret,char *types,int argc,...){
//#define push(w,h,t) *(t*)(w-sizeof(t))=h; w-=sizeof(t)
#define push(w) asm("push %0"::"r"(w))
    typedef void (*funcptr)(...);
    typedef char* char_ptr;
    funcptr func=(funcptr)ptr;
    double d;
    char *p;
    int n;
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl, argc);
    for(int i=0;i<argc;i++){
        switch(types[i]){
            case 'p':
                p=va_arg(vl,char_ptr);
                printf("Pushing char*: %s\n",p);
                push(p);
                break;
            case 'n':
                n=va_arg(vl,int);
                printf("Pushing int: %d",n);
                push(n);
                break;
            case 'd':
                d=va_arg(vl,double);
                printf("Pushing double: %f",d);
                push(d);
                break;
        }
    }
    va_end(vl);
    asm(
        "call *%0"
        ::"r"(func)
    );
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    //address can be directly set to lets say 0x450F10E0
    //we only know what is passed to function, we cant change function itself

    callfunc((void*)testfunc,'v',"p",1,"Hi!");
    return 0;
}
```

Could anybody help?

**Edit**
 Function I want to call is __stdcall.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142284/convert-inline-assembly-code-to-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294841/inline-assembly-language

Answer (score 1):

Don't mess around with `va_list`, this is highly non portable. In particular, many platform ABI's have argument passing of some parameters in registers, you are completely missing that aspect. (You didn't even tell us which ABI you are using.)

They way that is foreseen by the standard is to pass the `va_list` to the function that you want to call and do the interpretation of the arguments, there.