# Call C address as function without prototype

Tags: c, assembly, 64-bit

I need to call a function in C by just knowing it address, and no information
on it prototype (I can't cast it to a C function pointer).

The information I have on this function is it address.

I also know the parameters I want to pass to it (Thanks to a void pointer) and
the size of the arguments array (accessed trough the void pointer).

I also want to respect the C calling convention. For x86 version, I pretty much
know how to do it (allocate the space on the stack, copy the parameters to
that space and finally call the function).

The problem is with x64 convention (Linux one for now) where parameters are
passed through registers. I have no idea of the size of each parameter to fill
appropriately registers, I only know the size of the parameter array.

Also, I don't want to depend on gcc so I can't use __builtin_apply that seems
to be not standard and also be pretty dark.

I want to write my own piece of code to support multi compiler and also to
learn interesting stuff.

So basically, the function I want to write as the same prototype as
__builtin_apply which is:

```
void *call_ptr(void (*fun)(), void *params, size_t size);
```

I want also the code to write it in C (thanks to asm inline) or pure x64 asm.

So is there a way to do this properly and with respect of the calling
convention ? Or is this impossible with the x64 convention without knowing
exactly the prototype of the function called ?

Comment: Take a look at [libffi](http://sourceware.org/libffi/).

Comment: This could be a great alternative, but the problem with libffi is that it needs to know the type of each parameter and the return type of the function. I want to avoid gathering these informations to avoid loss of time if possible. So is that possible with x64 architecture ?

Comment: @Zerkan no it is not, you need the types of the parameters, there's no magic that can place parameters in the proper registers or stack space when calling a function without knowing the arguments

Comment: Read the ABI and write code that adheres to it.

Comment: @nos Well, I know the size of the void* array that represents arguments, so I can reserve enougth stack space with x86 convention. So my question was more is there a trick to do this with registers but it appears not.

Comment: You can't even do this on the x86 _in general_. It happens to work for one specific calling convention, but it doesn't work on e.g. Microsoft `__stdcall` (which is also the Win32 calling convention)

Comment: It's impossible with the x64 calling conventions, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142284/convert-inline-assembly-code-to-c/16146521

Answer (score 2):

Especially for x64 calling convention on Linux this will not work at all.

The reason is the very complicated calling convention.

Some examples:

```
void funcA(float64 x);
void funcB(int64 x);
```

In these two cases the value "x" is passed to the functions differently because floating point and integer are passed to the functions in different registers.

```
void funcC(float64 x,int64 y);
void funcD(int64 y,float64 x);
```

In these two cases the arguments "x" and "y" are in different order. However they are passed to the function in the same way (both functions use the same register for "x" and the same register for "y").

Conclusion: To create a function that does what you want you'd have to pass a string containing the argument types of each argument to the assembler function. The number/size of arguments is definitely not enough. However it would definitely be possible - as long as it must work only on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I think, all of your decision will not be supported multi-compiler, because the mechanism of passing arguments to function (registers, their order, stack, memory) - it's compiler dependence feature...

Comment: _"it's compiler dependence feature"_. Fortunately it isn't. At least not if the compiler adheres to the [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) of the target OS.

Comment: Yes, of course, it's supporting of some external low-level interfaces. But, supporting of ABI is compiler-dependence feature too =) Only one thing, that any compiler should supports exactly - Language Standart