# Replace Inline assembly code with C++

Tags: visual-c++, inline-assembly

I am working on 32-64 bit migration of a C++ project which contains some assembly code which is not supported on 64 bit platform. I would like to give a basic information about the project I have to migrate.

- Output of the project is a lib file which is used by another C++ project
- Here is the context which contain assembly code:

  ```
  int* a = Begin_args;
  int* b = End_args; (where Begin_args and End_args are int*)
  while (b > a)
  {
     int test = *(--b);
     __asm push test
  }
  ```
- So basically I have to replace the statement `__asm push test`

The issues I am facing are:

- I am not able to find out the pop statement for the same push statement
- I am not able to debug the project as output of the project is a lib file.
- I tried using stack, array, queue but didn't work out. It doesn't throw any compilation error but when launching application, it crashes.

So my question is:

- Can I debug any C++ project whose output is a lib file?
- I asked this question on some other forum also, someone told me to try `va_list` but I am not able to understand how `va_list` will work instead of `__asm push test`?
- So finally, how to replace this Asm code with C++/what to do to replace this Asm code?

Any help will be greatly appreciated as I am stucked in this issue from a long time.

Comment: If you do a debug build of both your application and the library, and use the debug build of the library for your application, then you should be able to debug the library.

Comment: `va_list` is probably the right answer here. Have you looked at any examples of how to use it?

Comment: Yes I looked but I am not able to understand how to use it here. Can you please tell me how can I use it in my code?
Thanks

Comment: Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142284/convert-inline-assembly-code-to-c (duplicate question)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that there may *not* be equivalent `pop` statements since it depends on the calling convention.

For example, if one of the x86 calling conventions, `sp` is the stack pointer that moves during the function and `bp` is the previous `sp` (from the next higher stack frame.

That means the epilog code for a function can be something like:

```
mov  sp, bp  ; just set sp to previous sp
pop  bp      ; pop previous sp
ret          ; and return
```

and it matters little what you've done with `sp` within the function. For example:

```
func:              ; here, the stack has return address
      push bp      ; push current bp
      mov bp, sp   ; put sp into bp

      sub  sp, 50  ; do whatever you want with sp here

      mov  sp, bp  ; just set sp to previous sp
      pop  bp      ; pop previous sp
      ret          ; and return
```

The `sub` instruction in that code above is often used for allocating space for local variables for the function. The parameters to the function were pushed before the call so can be accessed with `[bp+N]` and local variables can be accessed with `[bp-N]`.